Should real and imaginary components of a complex random variable be always independent of one another?
Suppose a complex random variable be given as:
$$z=x+jy$$
Orthogonality does not imply independence, however, does being real and imaginary components of a complex random variable guarantees independence, i.e., $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$, where $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are PDFs of $x$ and $y$.
Furthermore, I have obtained $z=x+jy$ by using polar to Cartesian transformation of $z=A\exp(j\theta)$ where $A=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$ and $A$ and $\theta$ are independent. Does independence of $A$ and $\theta$, implies independence of $x$ and $y$.

Depends on the distributions of $A$ and $\theta$. In particular, $P(x \ge 0, y\ge 0)$ need not be equal to $P(y \ge 0)P(y\ge 0)$ in general.


No. As a counterexample take $Z = (1+i)X$ where $X$ is, say, a
standard Gaussian random variable. Then both the real and imaginary parts of $Z$ are $X$, evidently not independent.
No, e.g. take $A$ some exponential random variable and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ deterministic. Then $X=Y$ with probability $1$ and they are not deterministic, hence they cannot be independent.

